# Dojo addOnUnload and xhrGet

Tags: ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I have function to unlock data sets via an API

```
function unlockData() {

    var xhrArgs = {
        url: "/api/unlockData",
        handleAs: "json",
        content: {
            account_id: accountId
          },
        load: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                alert("Data unlocked");
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong.");
            }

        },
        error: function(error) {
           alert("error:"+error);
        }
    }

    var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);

}
```

which is called onUnload

```
dojo.addOnUnload(window, "unlockData");
```

When reloading, this I get this error message:

```
Error: Unable to load /api/unlockData?account_id=981782 status:0
```

Can I fire an xhrGet request on unload at all? BTW, the function works fine, if not called on unload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Xhr calls are **asynchronous**, putting this call during the 'Unload' will fail always because the browser is not in this page anymore.

Anyways, since the `addOnUnload` is triggered during the `window.onbeforeunload`, you can put a "timer" loop to check if the AJAX call has success.

I **strongly** don't recommend this practice. Using an AJAX call during the "window" closing is totally unnecessary, you should consider to use a form instead and call your scripts **synchronously**

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used a from with an iframe as target. That did it.